# How to write response into Buffer instead of rendering on Screen?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, httpresponse

I am developing app where I need to capture an Information from Webpage after giving credentials automatically. Some how I managed to do Automatic login and redirection of page. Here is my code :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://abcd.com.au/categories/A_dfn/sdf");
    HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buf = new byte[10000];
    Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream();
    string s = null;
    int c = 0;
    do
    {
        c = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (c != 0) {
            s = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, c);
            sb.Append(s);
        }
    } while (c > 0);
    string oldhead = "class=\"login_button\">";
    string newhead = "class=\"login_button\">   <script type=\"text/javascript\">document.getElementById('btn').click()</script>";
    sb.Replace(oldhead, newhead);

    string oldbtn = "value=\"Submit\"";
    string newbtn = "value=\"Submit\" id=\"btn\" ";
    sb.Replace(oldbtn, newbtn);

    string oldAction = "<form action=\"/login\" method=\"post\">";
    string newAction = "<form action=\"https://abcd.com.au/login?orig_req_url=%2Fcategories/A_dfn/sdf\" method=\"post\">";
    sb.Replace(oldAction, newAction);

    string oldUsername = "<input id=\"login_email\" type=\"text\" name=\"user[email_address]\" class=\"textBox\" value=\"\">";
    string newUserName = "<input id=\"login_email\" type=\"text\" name=\"user[email_address]\" class=\"textBox\" value=\"abc@xyz.com.au\">";
    sb.Replace(oldUsername, newUserName);

    string oldPass = "<input id=\"login_password\" type=\"password\" name=\"user[password]\" class=\"textBox\" value=\"\">";
    string newPass = "<input id=\"login_password\" type=\"password\" name=\"user[password]\" class=\"textBox\" value=\"abc\">";
    sb.Replace(oldPass,newPass);
    Response.Write(sb);
```

This is show me expected output as I want by rendering page(Response.write(sb)). But, now I want to do same thing without redirecting to  "https://abcd.com.au/login?orig_req_url=%2Fcategories/A_dfn/sdf" and want to do more stuff on this. I expect to get output of Response.Write(sb) in some buffer. Is it possible to do?

Here is example, that explains exactly what I want to do.
I am looking for an product's qty say name : Screw 15mm, this resides in page https://abcd.com.au/%2Fcategories/A_dfn/sdf.
So, I am requesting this url first, but as need login to access that page, its redirecting me to login page, filling username and password, pressing login button by using javascript,and then redirected to Originally Requested page. And on this page I want to find for that product, and return information to my web app.

All this I want to do without showing to user. 
I just want to show retrieved information.

Thanks.

Comment: Can any one answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a persisted session. Your approach towards this problem is incorrect. You are triggering the submit on the client-side.  What you are trying to achieve should be done on the server-side.

The key to your scenario is to persist (store) the session & cookies set by the login page; then before your next request for the product info, inject the credential into the requesting webRequest.

1. Use the WebRequest object to load the login page.
2. Store any info (cookies) sent by the login page Response header.
3. create a new WebRequest object with the provided Response header, inject in userid/password.
4. Store any credentials returned by the Response.
5. Proceed to request for the quote info.

There is no generic way to do this without knowing the website you are trying to screen-scrap from. But the general step is as above.  Basically, you need to create a custom class for this.

Also, you need **HTMLAgilityPack** to parse the HTML nodes. It is the correct method.

---

**EDIT**: Added my codes. Just so happen that I've created this class before sometime ago. So, you're in luck. However, you will need HTMLAgilityPack installed & referenced to use it. You can download HAP at: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/  If you want to do any serious screen-scraping, HAP is the de-facto standard.

```
Public Class clsBrowserSession
    '=================================================================================================================================
    'This is a special Browser Post class
    ' Instead of just POST to a URL as per the clsWeb.fnsPostResponse()
    ' clsBrowserSession allows us to LOAD a page first, persist all the cookies and variables, and then only POST to the target URL.
    ' The reason is that some program will drop (lets say) a SessionID as an input when you first load the page.
    ' and when you post, without the SessionID (variable), it will reject the POST. Thus clsBrowserSession can solve this problem.
    '=================================================================================================================================
    ' USAGE:
    '   Dim voBrowserSession As New clsBrowserSession
    '   voBrowserSession.sbLoadPage("https://xxx.yyy.net.my/publicncdenq/index.htm")
    '   voBrowserSession.proFormElements("UserID") = "myID"
    '   voBrowserSession.proFormElements("Password") = "myPassword"
    '   Dim vsResponseHTML As String = voBrowserSession.Post("https://xxx.yyy.net.my/publicncdenq/index.htm")
    Private vbIsPostingInProgress As Boolean
    Public voCookies As System.Net.CookieCollection
    Public proHTMLDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Public proFormElements As clsFormElementCollection

    Public Sub sbLoadPage(pvsURL As String)
        vbIsPostingInProgress = False
        fnoCreateWebRequestObject().Load(pvsURL)
    End Sub
    Public Function Post(pvsURL As String) As String
        vbIsPostingInProgress = True
        fnoCreateWebRequestObject().Load(pvsURL, "POST")

        Return proHTMLDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml
    End Function

    Private Function fnoCreateWebRequestObject() As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
        Dim voWeb As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
        voWeb.UseCookies = True
        voWeb.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf event_OnPreRequest)
        voWeb.PostResponse = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PostResponseHandler(AddressOf event_OnAfterResponse)
        voWeb.PreHandleDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreHandleDocumentHandler(AddressOf event_OnPreHandleDocument)
        Return voWeb
    End Function
    Private Sub sbAddPostDataTo(pvoRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Dim vsPayload As String = proFormElements.fnsAssemblePostPayload()
        Dim vabyteBuffer As Byte() = Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vsPayload.ToCharArray())
        pvoRequest.ContentLength = vabyteBuffer.Length
        pvoRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        pvoRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
        pvoRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(vabyteBuffer, 0, vabyteBuffer.Length)
    End Sub
    Private Sub sbAddvoCookiesTo(pvoRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest)
        If (Not IsNothing(voCookies)) Then
            If voCookies.Count > 0 Then pvoRequest.CookieContainer.Add(voCookies)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub sbSaveCookiesFrom(pvoResponse As Net.HttpWebResponse)
        If pvoResponse.Cookies.Count > 0 Then
            If IsNothing(voCookies) Then voCookies = New Net.CookieCollection
            voCookies.Add(pvoResponse.Cookies)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub sbSaveHtmlDocument(pvoHTMLDocument As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)
        proHTMLDoc = pvoHTMLDocument
        proFormElements = New clsFormElementCollection(proHTMLDoc)
    End Sub

    Protected Function event_OnPreRequest(pvoRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest) As Boolean
        sbAddvoCookiesTo(pvoRequest)
        If vbIsPostingInProgress Then sbAddPostDataTo(pvoRequest)
        Return True
    End Function
    Protected Sub event_OnAfterResponse(pvoRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest, pvoResponse As Net.HttpWebResponse)
        sbSaveCookiesFrom(pvoResponse)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub event_OnPreHandleDocument(pvoHTMLDocument As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)
        sbSaveHtmlDocument(pvoHTMLDocument)
    End Sub

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Form Elements class
    '  Note: This element class will only capture (any) INPUT elements only, which should be enough
    '  for most cases. It can be easily modified to add other SELECT, TEXTAREA, etc voInputs
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Class clsFormElementCollection
        Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Public Sub New(htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)
            Dim voInputs As Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode) = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input")
            For Each voInput As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In voInputs
                Dim vsName = voInput.GetAttributeValue("name", "undefined")
                Dim vsValue = voInput.GetAttributeValue("value", "")
                If vsName <> "undefined" Then Add(vsName, vsValue)
            Next
        End Sub
        Public Function fnsAssemblePostPayload() As String
            Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
            For Each voKeyValuePair In Me
                Dim vsValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(voKeyValuePair.Value)
                sb.Append("&" & voKeyValuePair.Key & "=" & vsValue)
            Next
            Return sb.ToString.Substring(1)
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

Just make the above into a class object and instantiate it. The usage example is in the comment. You want the `vsResponseHTML` string.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your answer. I am so tiered by this problem that whatever you write, is bouncing from my head... Just kidding. Can you give some tutorial links so that I have some look. Thanks

Comment: Added the class for that. Good luck.